# Not able to convert php54 to php81

Tags: google-app-engine

Both the files get loaded properly with php54 and app.yaml as below

https://testphp81.el.r.appspot.com/contact.php

https://testphp81.el.r.appspot.com/index.php

```
 runtime: php55
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true
 automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1


 handlers:
  - url: /
    script: public/index.php
    secure: always
  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    script: public/\1
```

Another project with php81 and app.yaml does not work properly

https://jikwebsite.el.r.appspot.com/index.php , proper
https://jikwebsite.el.r.appspot.com/contact.php , **index.php gets loaded
**

```
runtime: php81
instance_class: F2


 handlers:
  - url: /
    script: public/index.php
    secure: always
  - url: /(.+\.php)$
    script: public/\1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#app_startup) for PHP 8.1

> If your app contains a public/index.php or index.php file, App Engine uses this file to serve your app.

My understanding of the above is that GAE will always go to that file and either display its contents or do some other routing based on the contents (i.e. if you add routing in the file; they provided an example in the documentation referenced above).

An alternative to having your routing in your index.php file is to use a framework to route your requests which is why the same documentation also says

> We recommend you use a framework, such as Laravel, Symfony, or Slim, because it provides lightweight routing for writing and deploying PHP apps quickly.

You'll notice that if you visit - https://jikwebsite.el.r.appspot.com/contact2.php, you still get 'index.php' instead of a 404. That's because GAE is simply always serving up the contents of your `index.php` file as they stated above.

However, if you visit https://testphp81.el.r.appspot.com/contact2.php, you get a 404 because contact2 doesn't exist and GAE uses the handler in `app.yaml` for routing requests when you're using PHP 5.5